# nested bootstrap components scaling breakpoints behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

Hello I am doing angular2 bootstrap components. To use bootstrap components I need to combine bootstrap components in a nested way. Problem now is when i design a component with a behaviour of breaking at certain pixels those are scaled when nested in a column. is this the wron way of designing angular2 bootstrap components or is there a workaround?

So the nested bootstrap row needs to behave like a separate viewport.